# Adding js variable to Ajax post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I am trying to add the variable "val" to an existing list of Ajax data

```
            var val = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=product/product/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select'),
```

Any ideas if or how this could be done?

Comment: Seeing as you're passing a jQuery object containing DOM elements to the `data` option, and that it's invalid data, I don't see why you would want to add a string to that as well ?

Comment: Yes - thanks to all. Back the drawing board